# Choose for which device the preview is shown, jetpack compose

Tags: android, preview, android-jetpack-compose

In the View system we could choose XML preview for different devices, but I could not find a way to choose preview device for Jetpack Compose.
How do we set preview for different devices while using Jetpack Compose?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/tooling/preview/Preview#device()

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
@Preview(device = Devices.PIXEL_2_XL)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MyApplicationFooTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

The list of available devices is here

```
object Devices {
    const val DEFAULT = ""

    const val NEXUS_7 = "id:Nexus 7"
    const val NEXUS_7_2013 = "id:Nexus 7 2013"
    const val NEXUS_5 = "id:Nexus 5"
    const val NEXUS_6 = "id:Nexus 6"
    const val NEXUS_9 = "id:Nexus 9"
    const val NEXUS_10 = "name:Nexus 10"
    const val NEXUS_5X = "id:Nexus 5X"
    const val NEXUS_6P = "id:Nexus 6P"
    const val PIXEL_C = "id:pixel_c"
    const val PIXEL = "id:pixel"
    const val PIXEL_XL = "id:pixel_xl"
    const val PIXEL_2 = "id:pixel_2"
    const val PIXEL_2_XL = "id:pixel_2_xl"
    const val PIXEL_3 = "id:pixel_3"
    const val PIXEL_3_XL = "id:pixel_3_xl"
    const val PIXEL_3A = "id:pixel_3a"
    const val PIXEL_3A_XL = "id:pixel_3a_xl"
    const val PIXEL_4 = "id:pixel_4"
    const val PIXEL_4_XL = "id:pixel_4_xl"

    const val AUTOMOTIVE_1024p = "id:automotive_1024p_landscape"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To add to @Francesc 's answer you can also create an annotation class and list different device setups with different screen sizes/densities. It's very handy if you need to check how everything is looking like across different devices like phones, tablets, etc.

```
@Preview(name = "phone", device = "spec:shape=Normal,width=360,height=640,unit=dp,dpi=480")
@Preview(name = "pixel4", device = "id:pixel_4")
@Preview(name = "tablet", device = "spec:shape=Normal,width=1280,height=800,unit=dp,dpi=480")
annotation class DevicesPreview
```

Then in your composable you can use:

```
@DevicesPreview
@Composable
fun ExampleComposablePreview() {
    ...
}
```

In this example you'll be seeing a small screen device and a tablet but it's totally customizable. Hope it helps :)